# Existe algum problema em usar arrays em um banco de dados?

Tags: banco-de-dados, array, tipagem, modelagem, tabela-banco-de-dados

Alguns sistemas gerenciadores de banco de dados, como o PostgreSQL por exemplo, possuem uma forma de armazenar *arrays* nas tabelas. Existe algum problema em fazer isso, já que não vejo muita gente usando?

Comment: Tem casos que delimito os valores com `,`, `;`, ou em casos mais complexos prefiro usar um `varchar` com um texto JSON dentro :)

Comment: Sim, um "CSV" costuma funcionar, ou algo mais simples dependendo do que tem de conteúdo, a pessoa só não terá nada pronto para tratar, mas sabendo usar vai bem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se fizer certo e não usar onde não precisa não tem problema.

As pessoas não usam porque:

- não conhecem ou não sabem usar bem, inclusive na aplicação
- existem outras soluções
- não é portável para outro fornecedor (quase nada além do muito básico é)
- em geral eles não são bem implementados no SGDB e tem muito detalhe que pode não sair como espera
- O ORM que a pessoa usa não entende isso

Ele é interessante quando você tem uma quantidade variável de elementos que podem ser considerados como uma única coluna e não vale a pena fazer a normalização e colocar em outra tabela, que terá menos eficiência.

Obviamente que esses dados precisam ser mais informativos e não precisam usar para buscar individualmente. Até dá para indexar todos os elementos e fazer buscas direto ali, mas pode não ser fácil ou não dar bom resultado quando eles são chave de acesso.

De fato, em todo banco de dados deveria ter uma forma simples de armazenar algo assim sem se valer de relações, já que o dado pode ser totalmente propriedade do objeto principal da tabela, é até uma anomalia colocar em outra tabela, mas que se tornou padrão em bancos de dados relacionais, e talvez deu má fama a ele e propiciou surgiu o tal do NoSQL.

O PostgreSQL cria algumas dificuldades para usar isso e outros que permitem eu não conheço muito, mas não deve ser muito simples também. Onde não tem um mecanismo próprio é possível simular, o que pode ser um benefício ou alguma coisa mais caótica. Alguns usam JSON para conseguir isso, até porque o formato já prevê uma forma de *array*.

É muito mais eficiente e prático em algumas situações, e pode ser a semântica mais correta.

Algumas pessoas são contra porque fere a normalização, mas isso é não olhar o contexto. Tem caso que o melhor é assim mesmo. Se alguém usar o *array* em um caso que os dados que se repetem são independentes aí é escolha errada. Quando a normalização foi criada ninguém imaginava que teria uma forma de fazer isso de maneira apropriada.

Ele funciona direitinho se usar da forma correta. E ele faz parte do SQL *standard*, mas os fornecedores não implementaram ou fizeram de forma diferente do padrão.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).